# C# Login error with text checking/validation

Tags: c#, text

So baiscally my first registered username and password in my text file when i login is able to pass through the validation however my next pair gets past the .contains but fails at checking password, not giving me the message and  closing the console.

Example of text file-

Elliot|Benten67Fred|Payne

It will be able to check Elliot and Benten67. However can locate Fred but not able to check if the password is right? Any help would be great

```
public void Register()
        {
            string filePath = @"/Users/elliot/Documents/Film Libary Software/Film-Libary/Film-Libary/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/UserInfo.txt";


            Console.WriteLine("Create A Username which contains A Upper Case character");


            Username = Console.ReadLine();
            bool usernameIsUpper = Username.Any(char.IsUpper);
            if (usernameIsUpper)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a password: ");
                Password = Console.ReadLine();
                string toWrite = Username + "|" + Password;
                File.AppendAllText(filePath, toWrite);
                Login();


            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Username: Please try again!");
                Register();
            }






        }

        public void Login()
        {
            string fileName = @"/Users/elliot/Documents/Film Libary Software/Film-Libary/Film-Libary/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/UserInfo.txt";

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
            {
                string line;
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your username");
                string loginUsername = Console.ReadLine();
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.Contains(loginUsername))
                    {
                        int indexOfDelimiter = line.IndexOf('|');
                        string usernameFromFile = loginUsername;
                        string passwordFromFile = line.Substring(indexOfDelimiter + 1, line.Length - (indexOfDelimiter + 1));
                        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your password");
                        string enteredPassword = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (enteredPassword == passwordFromFile)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Elliot well done");
                        }

                    }


                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: please post complete compilable source

Comment: @pm100 Hello does that mean all my code. Ive only got a options method and the Main program class. Would you want that?

Comment: really yes, we want to compile the code ourselves to test it. But I see your error anyway , You need  `File.AppendLine(toWrite)` not `appendalltext` , you are not writing a new line

Comment: @pm100 Hello, thanks for helping me but when it says that File does not contain a defintion for Append. There is appendalllines however i think thats for an array and my to write is just a string. Thanks

Comment: My bad, there is no AppendLine - instead do `string toWrite = Username + "|" + Password + "\n";`

Comment: @pm100 its fixed now. Thanks alot have a great night!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reading code requires the each user be on a separate line, but you are not writing new lines, you can see that here

```
Elliot|Benten67Fred|Payne
```

you need

```
Elliot|Benten67
Fred|Payne
```

The error is here

```
            string toWrite = Username + "|" + Password;
            File.AppendAllText(filePath, toWrite);
```

you need

```
            string toWrite = Username + "|" + Password + "\n";
            File.AppendAllText(filePath, toWrite);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks alot this solution works. Im learning c# and i think making this login and registration page has taught me alot already from pretty much scratch. Have  a great night!

Comment: @ElliotFreebairn tick this answer please, to say that it worked

Comment: @ElliotFreebairn you have other errors, see what happens if you have 2 users in the file, one called "ann" and onother called "anne", or even better "david" and "avi"

Comment: I will look at the errors tommorow, and will tick the answer. Thank you